# Google sheets : Open Drawing window on Cell edit by apps scrip?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible with Apps Script to popup the Drawing window on a clic of a Cell (Insert -> Drawing)

I want that the user insert a Scribble handwritten signature into a Cell in one click

Thanks!

Comment: If I wanted to do something like that I'd try using an html dialog first.  One can completely control the drawing on an html canvas with JavaScript.

Comment: Hi there @AlexBouchard! I strongly suggest the approach commented by @MetaMan. Please test it and write back sharing your results.